# What does $\overline {\cup I_n}$ mean?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

[image]

What does $\overline {\cup I_n}$ mean?

What does $ \cup \overline{I_n}$ mean?

Comment: $\bigcup_n I_n$ is a set. Given a set $S$, $\bar{S}$ typically denotes [the closure of the set $S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)#Closure_of_a_set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The closure of the union of all $I_n$
2. The union of the closures of each $I_n$